# Illustrator action to embed all external objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, actions, illustrator-scripting

To embed all external objects in Illustrator I do this:

- Open the Links panel
- Select all the linked objects (select first, shift+clik on last)
- Select Embed object(s) from the dropdown menu in the panel

But when recording those actions (macro), they are not being saved.

Is there a way to automate this process? Script?

Answer (score 3):

Embed is one of the commands you can't execute with an action (perhaps someone else can explain specifically why, I'm not sure).

You can do this with a really short script, here's an example of the code:

```
#target Illustrator

if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    while ( app.activeDocument.placedItems.length > 0 ) {
        placedArt = app.activeDocument.placedItems[0];
        placedArt.embed();
    }
}
```

Save this as a plain text file with the extension .jsx into this folder : "[install directory]Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2015\Presets\en_US\Scripts", restart Illustrator and run the script from File->Scripts.

Answer (score -2):

(Illustrator) To play a set of actions, select the set name, and click the **Play** button in the **Actions panel**, or choose **Play** from the panel menu.

To play an entire single action, select the action name, and click the **Play** button in the **Actions panel**, or choose **Play** from the panel menu.

If you assigned a key combination to the action, press that combination to play the action automatically.

To play only a part of an action, select the command from which you want to start playing, and click the **Play** button in the **Actions** panel, or choose **Play** from the panel menu.

To play a single command, select the command, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd>-click (Mac OS) the **Play** button in the Actions panel. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> (Mac OS), and double-click the command.

Comment: The problem is that the Embed action is not present in the action set list after recording.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the question is how to automate the embed process, it seems OP already knows how to use Actions in Illustrator.