# Illustrator Javascript to Embed Linked Images

Tags: adobe-illustrator, javascript

Hi I'm Trying to Embed linked Images in Adobe Illustrator. I've edited some Javascript code to get the linked Images to Embed and It works fine for 1, 2 an 3 Images. When I try to embed a fourth Image the Image jumps/moves position before it embeds.

Comment: Can you include your code here?

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple script* to embed **all** images in an Illustrator doc.

I just tested it on 6 images at once and it works.

```
if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    while ( app.activeDocument.placedItems.length > 0 ) {
        placedArt = app.activeDocument.placedItems[0];
        placedArt.embed();
    }
}
```

<sub>*I didn't create it myself, I'm not sure where exactly I got it from, but probably from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/71642/63979).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Welz, I'm still seeing the same result, the Graphics are changing position as they embed.

The code that worked for me is below. I had to set an array to stop the Images from Jumping:

```
                    var idoc = app.activeDocument.placedItems;
                    var iplaced = app.activeDocument.placedItems[0, 1];{
                    var  p = 0; p > iplaced.length; p++;
                    var iplaced = app.activeDocument.placedItems[0];
                    iplaced.embed();
                    var iplaced = app.activeDocument.placedItems[1];
                    iplaced.embed();
                    var iplaced = app.activeDocument.placedItems[1];
                    iplaced.embed();
```